# Build gdal with proj version 6

Tags: gdal, proj, compile

### Description of the issue:

Building [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) from [sources](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal) after having build proj in its latest version is failing at the configure step because it's not finding proj 6.

### Details to reproduce:

#### Work environment:

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit (`4.18.0-16-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

#### Installing proj.4 version 6:

I recently and freshly clone the master branch of `proj` version 6 from github: https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4 in order to build it:

```
git clone https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4.git /opt/proj.4
cd /opt/proj.4/
mkdir build/ && cd build/
cmake-gui ..
[configure] & [generate]
make
$ sudo checkinstall
```

Everything went fine, then:

```
$ proj -V
Rel. 6.1.0, September 1st, 2019
<proj>: 
projection initialization failure
cause: no arguments in initialization list
program abnormally terminated

$ which proj
/usr/local/bin/proj
```

#### Installing GDAL:

In a second stage, I downloaded `gdal` from GitHub as well: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal to build it from its master branch:

```
git clone https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal.git /opt/gdal
cd /opt/gdal/gdal
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-python=python3
```

#### The error:

And here is the tail of the result of the `./configure` step in the terminal:

```
checking for PROJ >= 6 library... checking for proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -linternalproj... no
configure: error: PROJ 6 symbols not found
```

#### Questions:

Is there a special way to tell `gdal` where to find the previously installed `proj` in its version 6.x.x?
If yes, how?

#### Documentation:

https://proj4.org/install.html#cmake
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-PROJ6-td5393781.html
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn

#### Updates:

The same error appears if I try with release 6.0.0 from OSGeo:
http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-6.0.0.zip
[ MD5 (proj-6.0.0.zip) = e0c6290f18852b963dabe5961c6f97d5 ]

[2019-10-04]

Some time passed, I used the following as simple as possible procedure - using releases - to install GDAL and still encounter some error:

1. Download and unzip PROJ release 6.2.0 from https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/releases.
2. `cd proj-6.2.0`
   `mkdir build && cd build`
   `cmake-gui` [configure] and [generat] with default except I changed `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`
   `make -j4`
   `sudo checkinstall`

Everything went fine.

Then, GDAL:
 1. Download and unzip GDAL release 3.1.0 from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases.
 2. `cd gdal-3.1.0`
    `./configure --enable-shared --with-python=python3 --with-proj=/usr/local CXXFLAGS="-Wall -std=c++17"`
    `make`

=> Error:

```
...bunch of:
/opt/gdal-3.0.1/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `proj_stuff`
/opt/gdal-3.0.1/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `proj_crs_get_sub_crs'
/opt/gdal-3.0.1/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `proj_crs_get_coordinate_system'
/opt/gdal-3.0.1/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `proj_create_conversion_wagner_vi'
/opt/gdal-3.0.1/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `proj_coordoperation_get_param_index'
/opt/gdal-3.0.1/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `proj_coordoperation_get_param_count'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile:82: recipe for target 'gdalinfo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gdal-3.0.1/apps'
GNUmakefile:112: recipe for target 'apps-target' failed
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

Answer (score 7):

You are in the right track, but you need to inform `gdal` that you are using your own version of `proj`, rather than the one supplied with Ubuntu.

Up until `gdal` v2.4.1, you would do that by providing the `--with-static-proj4=` configure argument. However, it has been deprecated in `gdal` v3.0.0. As a result, you should now use the simpler `--with-proj=`.

Therefore, your configure command should look something like this:

`./configure --with-python=python3 --with-proj=/usr/local`

Comment: for me doesn't work, still complaining about proj6, I've downloaded the repo from wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.0.0/gdal-3.0.0.tar.gz I'm compiling with `./configure -with-pg=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config` but even without it complains

Comment: @Sebastiano where did you install proj6 in your system? You should specify that path in the '--with-proj=' argument. You don't seem to be using that argument.

Comment: in some way I managed to install it, some problems with the cmake installation in Proj6 that they didn't appear in the log

Comment: Thanks for the hints, it looked good! But it didn't work with `--with-proj=/usr/local` from both a fresh install of PROJ and GDAL (see update in main question).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working with the `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables. It looked something like this for me

`CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/proj/include LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/proj/lib ./configure --prefix=/install/gdal/here`

Comment: for me brake everything if I do this

Answer (score 4):

I ended up writing a bootstrap script to configure GDAL 3.0.1 with PROJ 6.2.0, GRASS 7.8.0, GEOS 3.8.0, PostGIS 3.0.0. The order of compilation was:

1. PROJ
2. GEOS
3. GDAL (without GRASS)
4. GRASS
5. GDAL (with the configuration below)
6. PostGIS

I ended up compiling many of the dependencies which is why the `configure` command is such a mess. I was testing a bunch of different databases, hence oci, mysql, and postgres (pg). The java install is not the stock Ubuntu so be careful if you need that functionality.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# GDAL configuration script for Ubuntu 18.0.4
# Based upon https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu

./autogen.sh
MYCXXFLAGS='-I/usr/local/include'
MYLDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib'
MYCFLAGS=
LDFLAGS="$MYLDFLAGS" CFLAGS="$MYCFLAGS" CXXFLAGS="$MYCXXFLAGS" \
./configure \
  --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.8 \
  --with-crypto=yes \
  --with-opencl=yes \
  --with-geos=yes \
  --with-curl=/usr/bin/curl-config \
  --with-xml2=/usr/bin/xml2-config \
  --with-libkml=yes \
  --with-mysql=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config \
  --with-netcdf=/usr/local \
  --with-pcraster=internal \
  --with-pg=yes \
  --with-proj=/usr/local \
  --with-cryptopp=no \
  --with-java=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 \
  --with-libjson-c=internal \
  --with-libz=/usr/local \
  --with-hdf5=/usr/local \
  --with-expat=yes \
  --with-oci=yes \
  --with-oci-lib=/usr/local/lib/oracle/instantclient \
  --with-oci-include=/usr/local/lib/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include \
  --with-geotiff=yes \
  --with-grass=/usr/local/grass78 \
  --with-spatialite=yes \
  --with-freexl=yes
```

Answer (score 2):

I went through this process myself for a few hours. On the default location of my system an old version of proj was installed,  which frustrated the installation of gdal. I downloaded latest version of proj (proj-6.2.0) and gdal (gdal-3.0.0) installed it in my preferred location using the "classical" way. 
(in the example below this is `${HOME}/usr/local)`. Assuming that the tar ball of the proj-6.2.0 and gdal-3.0.0 are located in the `${HOME}/Download` then below follows the sequence of commands which worked for me. (Using ubuntu 18.08, note that the make process of the gdal-3.0.0 could take several hours depending on your system.):

```
export PREFIX=${HOME}/usr/local;
cd ${HOME}/Download/proj-6.2.0;
./configure --prefix=${PREFIX};
make install;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PREFIX}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH};
export PATH=${PREFIX}/bin:${PATH};
cd ${HOME}/Download/gdal-3.0.0;
CPPFLAGS=-I${PREFIX}/include LDFLAGS=-L${PREFIX}/lib ./configure --prefix=${PREFIX};
make ;
make install;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [GDAL build script](https://github.com/johntruckenbrodt/pyroSAR/blob/master/pyroSAR/install/install_deps.sh) some while ago which should contain all necessary steps.
A lot of info can also be found on this page [here](http://scigeo.org/articles/howto-install-latest-geospatial-software-on-linux.html). This should work:

```
./configure --with-static-proj4=/usr/local
```

I also read somewhere that building GDAL directly with its Python bindings is not recommended. You can find an alternative approach in the script.

Comment: those instruction from the link are a bit outdated it use proj 4 that is irrelevant as gdal needs proj 4 v6.